# Copy and paste as values to another sheet

Tags: vba, excel, copy-paste

I'm using the below code for copy paste data from one sheet to another sheet in the next available cell.

```css
Range("B" & i).Copy Sheet3.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
```

Is there any other way to copy paste as values in a single line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just transfer the value(s) directly.

```
Sheet3.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = sheet1.Range("B" & i).value
```